# Nuxt.js date time format

Tags: vue.js, datetime, nuxt.js, date-format

I have this html:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <h2><strong>Title: </strong>{{story.title}}</h2>  
            <p><strong>Score: </strong>{{story.score}}</p>  
            <p><strong>Author: </strong>{{story.by}}</p>  
            <p><strong>Date: </strong>{{ formatDate(story.time) }}</p>
            <!--<p><strong>Date: </strong>{{ dateFormat(new Date(story.time*1000),v) }}</p> -->   
            <NuxtLink :to="`/${story.id}`">
            <p class="btn my-4">View details</p> </NuxtLink>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and this scripts:

```html
<script setup>
const { story } = defineProps(['story']) 
    export default {
        
        data () {
            return {
            time: 0,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            formatDate(time) {
                date = new Date(time).format("YYYY/MM/DD")
                return date
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am not getting this kinda date format: "YYYY/MM/DD".
Please help how can I do that in Nuxt.js?

Comment: I recommend the usage of date-fns: https://date-fns.org/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there isn't a single function call to achieve that. I would suggest you re-writing your `formatDate` using [Date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to have full control of your format.

In addition, do not use `export default` in your [`<script setup>`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html). It's not a valid syntax.

```html
<script setup>
// Your other setup

function formatDate(time) {
    const date = new Date(time);
    
    // Get year, month, and day part from the date
    const year = date.toLocaleString("default", { year: "numeric" });
    const month = date.toLocaleString("default", { month: "2-digit" });
    const day = date.toLocaleString("default", { day: "2-digit" });
    
    return `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not worked. Error occured: [plugin:vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc] <script setup> cannot contain ES module exports. If you are using a previous version of <script setup>, please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227.

Comment: Do not use `export default` in your [`<script setup>`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html). Please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dayjs (tested with Nuxt 2.15)

```
yarn add @nuxtjs/dayjs
```

```js
    export default {
      // ...
      modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/dayjs'
      ],

    <template>
    <div>
    {{ $dayjs(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD') }}
    </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intl.DateTimeFormat method to do this if you dont want day.js (great library).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#instance_properties

```
let options = {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
      };
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(new Date(module.date))
    });
```